# How to do addition for multiple selects?

Tags: jquery, html, select, onchange

I would like to use 2 selects to change the value of the total price.

```
<span id="totalprice">$10</span>

<select id="upgrade1">
    <option value="10">A</option>
    <option value="20">B</option>
</select>
<select id="upgrade2">
    <option value="10">C</option>
    <option value="20">D</option>
</select>
```

So for example selecting B and D the total price would reflect $40.

This is my jQuery I have so far, but I do not know what goes into the addition part...

```
$('#upgrade1, #upgrade2').on('change', function() {
    $('#totalprice').text($(this).val());
});
```

How do I do the jQuery addition part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were missing closing tags (`</select>`) on your dropdown elements. See the code below, and use this jsFiddle to see it in action. http://jsfiddle.net/3eVc6/

**HTML:**

```
<span id="totalprice">$10</span>

<select id="upgrade1">
    <option value="10">A</option>
    <option value="20">B</option>
</select>
<select id="upgrade2">
    <option value="10">C</option>
    <option value="20">D</option>
</select>
```

**JavaScript (include jQuery library)**

```
$('#upgrade1, #upgrade2').on('change', function () {
    sum = Number($('#upgrade1').val()) + Number($('#upgrade2').val());
    $('#totalprice').html('$' + sum);
});
```

**Thanks to @Blazemonger for pointing out that `parseInt(val)` could possibly lead to parsing issues (since the radix is not specified). I've replaced it with `Number()`**

Comment: [Always, always, always use a radix with parseInt.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/850341/how-do-i-work-around-javascripts-parseint-octal-behavior)

Comment: @Blazemonger: You're right. Number() would be a better option because it avoids the parsing issues, and can return a floating point number (which may be preferable in the OP's example, since he's dealing with price).

Answer (score 0):

### HTML:

*Some small corrections - closing select statements*

```
<span id="totalprice">30</span>

<select id="upgrade1">
    <option value="10">A</option>
    <option value="20">B</option>
</select>
<select id="upgrade2">
    <option value="10">C</option>
    <option value="20">D</option>
</select>
```

### Javascript (jQuery):

*Get the value of each required field, passing through `parseInt` to convert to number, and add them together*

```
$('#upgrade1, #upgrade2').on('change', function() {
  $('#totalprice').text("$"+parseInt($('#upgrade1').val())+parseInt($('#upgrade2').val()));
});
```

Comment: Always use a radix with parseInt.

Comment: You forgot to add the $ sign. Thanks for helping.

Comment: @Blazemonger why is it necessary, when it defaults to base 10. Is there any problem with using the default base?

Comment: [If given certain strings, parseInt may default to base eight instead.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5600366/why-does-the-radix-for-javascripts-parseint-default-to-8)

Comment: @Blazemonger Wow - that is surprising! Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

You are very close already.

```
$('#upgrade1,#upgrade2').on('change', function() {
    $('#totalprice').text("$" + (parseInt($('#upgrade1').val(),10) +
                                 parseInt($('#upgrade2').val(),10)) );
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The "$" + changes the numbers back to strings and you get $1010 instead of $20.

Comment: Added another set of parentheses to take care of the numerical addition.