# jQuery suming two different number and subtracting them

Tags: jquery, html, forms

Can I ask on how to attack this function (total score - par score). But it's tricky because if a hole hasn't been played the par should not be subtracted from current score. Here's what I've tried so far with hidden fields:

```
$("#scorecard").change(function() {
    var totalscore = 0;
    $("#scorecard input:hidden").each(

    function() {
        totalscore += parseInt($(this).val())
    });
    $("#score").val(totalscore * -1);
}).change();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hireconor/DDfbf/11/

Comment: [`parseInt($(this).val(),10)`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5600366/901048)

Comment: You have multiple form elements with identical IDs (such as `<input type="hidden" id="par01" value="0">`). This is a no-no -- IDs must be unique, and JavaScript will assume they are.

Instead, give them a common class or, in the case of radio buttons, a common name which you can select as `$('[name=par01]')`

Comment: javascript will not assume ID's are unique, but will just give back the first it find's in DOM.