# Javascript switch wrong case

Tags: javascript, jquery, switch-statement, case, default

Hello (yet again) a question about javascript, this one has to be an easy one but I just can't see what I did wrong, I think something really stupid:

I have a textbox and a button. When i click the button the value wil be passed to a variable called activiteitn. Code:

```
    activiteitn = $("#m2activiteitn").val();
```

It gets the value, so when I filled in the number 1, activiteitn = 1.
After that I have a switch that looks like this:

```
        switch(activiteitn) {
        case  1: activiteitn = 1.2;
        break;
        case  2: activiteitn = 1.375;
        break;
        case  3: activiteitn = 1.55;
        break;
        case  4: activiteitn = 1.725;
        break;
        case  5: activiteitn = 1.9;
        break;
        default: alert("hoi");
        break;
        }
```

The problem is that even if I fill in the number 1, it jumps to the default case, causing it to alert. If I place a alert at case 1 that alert does not show up. The first thing that came in my mind was that the activiteitn was not 1, so right after the switch I placed another alert:

```
        alert (activiteitn);
```

Now, first what happends is I get the alert "hoi", then I get the second alert of activiteitn that says: 1. So after that I thought, "Maybe its a string", so I changed the cases to strings like: case "1" & case ("1") but that did not work either. The problem, it always goes to the default case and I can not figure out why that is, I hope someone sees what I did wrong and can help me out.

Comment: maybe you need strings in your case statement (case '1':...)

Comment: `activiteitn = parseInt($("#m2activiteitn").val(), 10);`

Comment: Did you try `parseInt(activiteitn)` before throwing it to `switch()`??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.val()` returns a string, not a number. So after the line:

```
activiteitn = $("#m2activiteitn").val();
```

the variable `activiteitn` actually equals `"1"`, not `1`. Since [`case...switch` uses strict equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6989902/is-it-safe-to-assume-strict-comparison-in-a-javascript-switch-statement), your test will always fail.

To fix, simply change the above line to:

```
activiteitn = +$("#m2activiteitn").val(); // convert to a number
```

or

```
activiteitn = parseInt($("#m2activiteitn").val(),10); // convert to an integer
```

or

```
activiteitn = parseFloat($("#m2activiteitn").val()); // convert to a float
```

Comment: Thanks, I did't know it was a string, even though I tried string cases.

Answer (score 1):

Use `parseInt(activiteitn, 10);` to turn your String into an Integer. Switch-case statements in Javascript don't play nicely with Strings half the time.

Comment: [Always use a radix with parseInt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5600366/why-does-the-radix-for-javascripts-parseint-default-to-8)