# take two times different value for different variable from one function

Tags: javascript, html

i am creating calculator when i click plus(+) operator i put the value in global variable which i get from input field and i do blank input field, but i have to take value from input which i enter second time and i have to keep another variable. that is i am trying to do but i  don't understand how to do this.

JS Fiddle URL: http://jsfiddle.net/ravianexpert/9q6Xu/1

Please help me

```
var operation="";
var restValue="";
var lastValue="";

function operator(op){
    if(op == '+'){
        alert("Plus");
        restValue = Number(document.getElementById("display").value);
        document.getElementById("display").value="";
        if(restValue == ""){
            alert("Zero");
        }else{
            lastValue = Number(document.getElementById("display").value);
        }
        //document.getElementById("display").value=restValue + lastValue;
    }
    console.log("restValue : " + restValue);
    console.log("lastValue : " + lastValue);
    console.log("operation : " + operation);
    //lastValue = restValue.charAt(restValue.length - 1);
    //console.log(lastValue)
}

<div class="container">
    <div id="lastCalculation"></div>
    <input type="text" step="any" size="16" value="0" id="display" readonly />
    <div class="keypad">
        <span class="clear" onclick="reset()">C</span>
        <span class="del" onclick="deleteValue()">Del</span>
        <div class="clr"></div>
        <span onclick="setNum(7)">7</span>
        <span onclick="setNum(8)">8</span>
        <span onclick="setNum(9)">9</span>
        <span onclick="operator('/')">/</span>
        <span onclick="setNum(4)">4</span>
        <span onclick="setNum(5)">5</span>
        <span onclick="setNum(6)">6</span>
        <span onclick="operator('*')">*</span>
        <span onclick="setNum(1)">1</span>
        <span onclick="setNum(2)">2</span>
        <span onclick="setNum(3)">3</span>
        <span onclick="operator('-')">-</span>
        <span onclick="setNum(0)">0</span>
        <span onclick="setNum('.')">.</span>
        <span class="isEqualTo" onclick="calculate()">=</span>
        <span onclick="operator('+')">+</span>
        <div class="clr"></div>
    </div><!-- keypad -->
</div><!-- container -->
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: setNum is not defined

Comment: Ravi prepare a demo fiddle please

Comment: ok pilot i am trying to do in fiddle once i complete let you know.

Comment: @ Pilot please find the link of js fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/ravianexpert/9q6Xu/

Comment: and i don't know why there is displaying the error "set num is not defined"

Comment: @Ravi: In the fiddle you need to set it to *"wrap in head"* (menu on left side, second drop-down). It indicates where your script should be placed in the resulting document shown in the lower right window.

Comment: yes its working now. i am sharing new url of js fiddle please me.

@user13500 : http://jsfiddle.net/ravianexpert/9q6Xu/1/

Comment: @ pilot please find the new fiddle URL : http://jsfiddle.net/ravianexpert/9q6Xu/1/

Comment: Updated my answer...with a demo as well

Comment: @Ravi: Is this some sort of school project? Can you use prototype etc. with `this` ?

Comment: @user13500 sorry i have to use only javascript even i don't have to use "eval". :)

Comment: @Ravi: `eval` is (in most cases) evil and something you should stay far away from. `prototype` as well as `eval` *is* Javascript, but if you are learning trough some course then it usually means that you only can use "*what you have learned so far*". That is why I asked if it was a school project.

Comment: @user13500 hmmm it is not school project its my own project which is given by my one of the childhood friend he kept some conditions for it like i don't have to use "eval". actually i all ready done by "eval".

Answer (score 1):

Updated 2016-05-29

Ran into a great [answer by @yckart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18082175/2827823), that **doesn't** use the evil [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) but the [`Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) constructor, so here is a demo showing how you can do to make the calculation work properly.

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function (e) {

  var op = document.querySelector('input').value;        
  alert('Using new Function: ' + calculate(op) + '\nUsing eval(): ' + evil_eval(op));   // if default is used => 40.4
  
})

function calculate(op){
  return new Function('return ' + op)();
}

// added for test purpose, showing they return the same value
function evil_eval(op) {
  return eval(op);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="12/5*9+9.4*2"> <button>Calc</button>
```

Src: [Calculate string value in javascript, not using eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479236/calculate-string-value-in-javascript-not-using-eval)

Comment: Well, dealing with issues like "empty" value etc., Ravi will fix

Comment: Thanks @PellePenna you did for me but i don't have to use "eval" for this, so i am doing, if i get any resolution for it i will post here. Thank you very much. :)