# using jquery to calculate HTML input value automatically

Tags: jquery

i have the following Html

```
<input class="top-display" value="5+5" id="display" disabled="disabled"> </input>
<button class="btn" > submit </button>
```

And jquery

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    var selected = $('#display').val();
    alert(selected);

});
```

[fiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/pt44c31p/2/)
my focus for this code is letting jquery to automatically do the math for me. like instead of jquery alerting "5+5" it should alert "10". and if the value = "5-5" is should alert "0"; without adding any if statement.

Comment: A quick solution is to change `$('#display').val()` to `eval($('#display').val())`. Although [Eval can be dangerous](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval). Make sure you read about it and understand it.

Comment: why didn't you ask at Stack Overflow? http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773

Comment: cos i cant ask there thanks to some pple who go around down-rating question for no good reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You can use eval()

> The eval() method evaluates JavaScript code represented as a string.

Change your code to this:

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    var selected = eval($('#display').val());
    alert(selected);
});
```

Also note:

> *eval() is a dangerous function, which executes the code it's passed with the privileges of the caller.*

Read more at MDN to understand the risks involving **eval**.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Answer (score 2):

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pt44c31p/3/)

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    var selected = $('#display').val();
    alert(eval(selected));
});
```

Don't forget to add proper error handling to avoid errors in the situations where there are in compatible values.

**Edit:** 
The `eval` function has known [security vulnerabilities](http://24ways.org/2005/dont-be-eval). It is always advisable not to use it.

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    var selected = $('#display').val();
    alert(evil(selected));
});

function evil(fn) {
    return new Function('return ' + fn)();
}
```

This is another solution I found in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18082175/1479535).

Answer (score 1):

Reason why you are getting 5+5 in alert is because your 'expression' is not executed. Where eval(args) will execute the arguments.

Answer (score 1):

**eval()** can be used in this case as long as you sanitize the input string like below:

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    // strip anything other than digits, (), -+/* and .
    var selected = $('#display').val().replace(/[^-()\d/*+.]/g, '');
    alert(eval(selected ));
});
```

You can also refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479236/calculate-string-value-in-javascript-not-using-eval) for other alternatives to **eval()**. The security risks of using **eval()** has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea) in great detail.

Cheers!

EDIT: Updated fiddle link [here](https://jsfiddle.net/pt44c31p/8/) for testing.