# Why is my JavaScript Code only working when I use a function with an capital letter?

Tags: javascript, function

I am new at coding and my new project is to code an calculator with JavaScript, HTML and CSS.
So, when I name the function in HTML part and JavaScript part which is in this code named as "clearA()" to "clear()" the function is not working. But clearA(), the function with an capital letter is working, why? It is confusing because other functions without capital letters are working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <script>
           function appendOperation(operation) {
    document.getElementById("resultArea").innerHTML +=operation;
}

function calculateResult() {
    let container = document.getElementById('resultArea');
    let result = eval(container.innerHTML);
    container.innerHTML = result;
}

function deleteLast() {
let container = document.getElementById('resultArea');
if(container.innerHTML.endsWith(' ')) {
    container.innerHTML = container.innerHTML.slice(0, -3);
    } 
    else {
    container.innerHTML = container.innerHTML.slice(0, -1);
        }
}
function clearA() {
    document.getElementById('resultArea').innerHTML = '';
    

    
}

function calculatingDecimal(operation) {
   let calculation= document.getElementById('resultArea').innerHTML += operation;
    eval(calculation);
}
</script>

</head>

<style>
body {
    background-color: black;
    font-family: 'Changa', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
}

table {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70vh;
    background-color: rgb(30, 30, 30);
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

td {
  font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: black;
}

td:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.operation-button {
    color: white;
    background-color: rgb(10, 146, 187);
}

.operation-button:hover {
    background-color: rgb(6, 174, 225);
}

.changing-button {
    background-color: rgb(53, 53, 53);
    color: white;
}

.changing-button:hover {
    background-color: rgb(96, 93, 93);
}

.numbers:hover {
background-color: rgb(14, 13, 13);
}

#resultArea {
    height: 30vh;
    color: white;
    font-size: 64px;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: flex-end;
    padding: 24px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#resultarea:hover {
    color: #0a92bb;
}
</style>


<body>

<div id="resultArea"></div>

<table>
   <tr>
  
    <td onclick="changingPresign()" class="changing-button">±</td>
    <td onclick="calculatingDecimal('/ 100')"class="changing-button">%</td>
    <td onclick="squared()" class="changing-button">x²</td>
    <td onclick="appendOperation(' / ')" class="operation-button">/</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="numbers" onclick="appendOperation(7)">7</td>
    <td class="numbers" onclick="appendOperation(8)">8</td>
    <td class="numbers" onclick="appendOperation(9)">9</td>
    <td onclick="appendOperation('*')" class="operation-button" >×</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td  class="numbers" onclick="appendOperation(4)" >4</td>
    <td  class="numbers" onclick="appendOperation(5)" >5</td>
    <td  class="numbers" onclick="appendOperation(6)" >6</td>
    <td  onclick="appendOperation('-')" class="operation-button" >-</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="numbers" onclick="appendOperation(1)" >1</td>
    <td class="numbers" onclick="appendOperation(2)" >2</td>
    <td class="numbers" onclick="appendOperation(3)" >3</td>
    <td  onclick="appendOperation('+')" class="operation-button" >+</td>
    <td onclick="clearA()" class="changing-button">AC</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="numbers"  onclick="appendOperation(0)" colspan="2">0</td>
    <td onclick="appendOperation('.')">,</td>
    
   
    <td class="operation-button" onclick="calculateResult()" id="result">=</td>
    <td id="ac" onclick= "deleteLast()" class="changing-button">CE</td>

   </tr>

</table>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because clear() is reserved for a function from JavaScript itself: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/clear

Comment: But `clear` is a method of `Set`. This is also valid: `var clear=12`

Comment: If you want to rename the function from "clearA()" to "clear()", you have to change the following statement from `<td onclick="clearA()" class="changing-button">AC</td>` to `<td onclick="clear()" class="changing-button">AC</td>`

Comment: I did what you said previously but it did not work.

Comment: First, you need to press F12 to show the console and then click the button to check if any error message would come out.

Comment: @Roy you're right, but it will be calling [`document.clear()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/clear), not set.clear()

Comment: It's not the capital letter; it's anything that makes the name different from "clear".  The problem has to do with using inline `onclick` attributes, because of the somewhat weird way that the event handler function is constructed from the attribute values.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes, you're right.

Comment: @65sami be aware your code is using 2 bad practices here, `onclick` and `eval`. Neither should be used. Use [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead of `onclick` and [this approach to build a calculator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32292231/how-to-code-a-calculator-in-javascript-without-eval) instead of `eval()`.

Comment: thank you, I´ll adjust my code accordingly

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan You are absolutely right!