# jquery calculate dynamic equation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to perform calculation on dynamic string.

I will get an equation from db named rule through ajax.
the rule may contain equation with operators like +,-,*,/,%.

how to perform this calculation?

```
  for (var i = 0; i < rules.length; i++) {
          var rule = rules[i].rule; // may contain $structurename1$*$structurename2$/$structurename3$ like this
          $('form :input[type="text"]').each(function(index,value){
              rule = rule.replace('$'+$(this).attr('structurename')+'$',$(this).val());
          });
  }

$('#result').val(rule);
```

Comment: Please provide us the code you've done yet so we can improve it all together.

Comment: unsafe but `eval("(10+5)*2")`; That in itself is safe, but when you replace that with a user entered variable value, you are giving them access to run code via that eval.

Comment: i have input string like this ** "70+30" ** and i just need the result should be "100"

Comment: We have not asked you to describe your code, we have asked you to post it directly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479236/calculate-string-value-in-javascript-not-using-eval# this post goes over a few options.

Answer (score 1):

[Calculate string value in javascript, not using eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479236/calculate-string-value-in-javascript-not-using-eval#)

Using a combination of code from above link:

**1.** Strip anything in formula that thats not a number, parenthesis, OR operator.

**2.** evalulate formula as function

Modified to return `NaN` if the function errors due to invalid input. Which shouldn't happen due to the `RegExp` replacements in step 1.

```
function calc(fn) {
  var formula = fn.replace(/[^-()\d/*+.]/g, '');
  try {
    return new Function('return ' + formula)();
  } catch (err) {
    return NaN;
  }
}
```

**DEMO:**
https://jsfiddle.net/tjywg716/

Answer (score -1):

```
var str_expression=textbox1.text();
var result=eval(str_expression);
textbox2.text(result);
```