# String To Number Confusion

Tags: javascript, jquery, parseint

Why does `parseInt("-1000-500-75-33")` return `-1000`?

Shouldn't it return the sum of those numbers: `-1608`

How can I get the string `"-1000-500-75-33"` to return as the sum of those numbers?

Comment: `eval("-1000-500-75-33").toString()`?

Comment: @Hodrobond that worked, thanks! If you post that as an answer, I'll give you props

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`parseInt` will try to get a number starting from the beginning of the string.

Since `-` is a valid character to begin a number with, it parses the string until it finds something invalid. The second `-` is invalid because no integer can contain an `-` inside it, only digits. So it stops there and considers the number to be "finished".

---

Now, if you want to *process* the expression, you can use `eval` like so:

```
eval("-1000-500-75-33")
```

This will return `-1608` as expected.

Answer (score 1):

`parseInt` will not perform any computations, rather it will try to convert a string into an integer. It returns `-1000` because the dash afterwards would not be considered a valid number.  If you want to sum all these numbers you could split on the dash, map to Number, then reduce:

```
var numString = "-1000-500-75-33";
numString.split('-').map(e => Number(e)).reduce((a, b) => a - b);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since they are in a string, ParseInt does not parse the whole string, just finds the first applicable number from the start & returns it. If the start of the string cannot be parsed, it returns `NaN`

```
parseInt("-1000NOT_NUMBER") = -1000
parseInt("test-1000`) = NaN
```

You have to use `eval` function to do what you want, that evaluates given string as if it were a command entered into the console;

```
eval("-1000-500-75-33") = -1608
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to [eval!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) [it's safe here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479236/calculate-string-value-in-javascript-not-using-eval)

`eval("-1000-500-75-33").toString()`

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(eval("-1000-500-75-33").toString());
```

And about type casting: After parsing -1000, which is obviously "negative 1000", It will escape casting as soon as it detect a symbol common between numbers & strings. So `parseInt` is seeing `"-1000-500-75-33"` as `"-1000NotConvertableString"`, So left the remaining away, returning `-1000` as the result of type-casting.