# Javascript getElementByID from form input

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, getelementbyid

I am providing a form where the user shall enter an arithmetic calculation. Further down the result shall appear, once the user hits enter. It might just be a problem of syntax, but I couldn't find the mistake. Here is what I did so far:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>What do you want to calculate?</p>
<form method="post"><span>Type here:</span><input type="text" id="calc"></input>
</form>
<script>
num_field = document.getElementById("calc");
num_field.onsubmit=function ()
{
    document.getElementById("display_result").innerHTML = num_field;
}
</script>
<p id="display_result"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

So, the user shall enter for instance "1+2". The result shall appear below.
Any idea where is my mistake?

Best regards

Comment: [input-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) is self-closing and should not have end tag.

Answer (score 1):

You were nearly there, your code just needed a bit of tweaking - see below (comments in code as what I have done and why)

The following seems to be an alternate and safer way to do this without using eval (function taken from the [second answer in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479236/calculate-string-value-in-javascript-not-using-eval#answer-18082175)):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <p>What do you want to calculate?</p>
  <form method="post" id="form">
    <span>Type here:</span>
    <input type="text" id="calc">              <!-- inputs are self closing no need for closing tag -->
    <input type="submit" value="submit">       <!-- added a submit button -->
  </form>
  <script>
    form = document.getElementById("form");
    num_field = document.getElementById("calc");
    form.onsubmit = function() {                                              // attach this event to the form
      document.getElementById("display_result").innerHTML = evalAlternate(num_field.value);  // add .value here to get the value of the textbox
      return false;                                                           // return false so form is not actually submitted and you stay on same page (otherwise your display result will not be updated as the page is reloaded
    }

 
    function evalAlternate(fn) {             // function safer alternate to eval taken from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479236/calculate-string-value-in-javascript-not-using-eval
      fn = fn.replace(/ /g, "");
      fn = fn.replace(/(\d+)\^(\d+)/g, "Math.pow($1, $2)");
      return new Function('return ' + fn)();
    }
  </script>
  <p id="display_result"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks, Pete.

Comment: Actually, I just noticed that there is a slight problem. Potency should be recognised, right? If I enter 2^2 it gives me 0.

Comment: Not sure if there is a function that will recognise that in js - don't even think eval would - what answer would you expect and how do you come to that answer - I've never seen that in maths before

Comment: Well, in that case, I would maybe display message like "cannot solve it!". Otherwise it looks like it calculates wrong. I will work on it. Thanks.

Comment: I googled it and found it means to power - you could write in some functionality to see if there is a ^ and then use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can achieve that.

`eval` is the best way for doing that but `eval` is risky to use so make sure to sanitize the value of input before using `eval`.

I am using this regex `/(^[-+/*0-9]+)/g` to extract only numbers and few operators `(-+/*)` and doing eval on that value.

remove the `<form>` that is not required use `keypress` event listener and check for enter key. *keycode of enter key is 13*

```js
num_field = document.getElementById("calc");
num_field.onkeypress = function(e) {
  if(e.which==13)
  {
     var value = num_field.value.match(/(^[-+/*0-9]+)/g);
     if(!value) return;
     else value = value[0];
     var res = eval(value);
     document.getElementById("display_result").innerText = res;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>What do you want to calculate?</p>
  <span>Type here:</span>
  <input type="text" id="calc" />
<p id="display_result"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks very much. It works like a charm. Just what I was looking for.

Comment: @user9 You can accept the answer to help other know the correct answer. If it worked for you, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```js
calc = document.getElementById("calc");
formula = document.getElementById("formula");
calc.addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById("display_result").innerHTML = eval(formula.value);
});
```

```html
<p>What do you want to calculate?</p>
<span>Type here:</span>
<input type="text" id="formula" />
<button id="calc" type="submit">calc</button>
<p id="display_result"></p>
```

[`eval()` JavaScript Method](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

Comment: eval() is evil
https://duckduckgo.com/?q=eval+is+evil&atb=v63-1__&ia=web

Comment: Thanks again for all the alternatives. I learnt a lot. I think which one I should prefer depends on the concrete task.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var calculation_input = document.getElementById('calculation_input');
calculation_input.onkeydown = function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 13) { // Enter key.
    // Sanitize before using eval()
    var calculation = calculation_input.value.replace(/[^-()\d/*+.]/g, '');
    document.getElementById("display_result").innerHTML = eval(calculation);
  }
}
```

```html
<p>What do you want to calculate?</p>
<span>Type here:</span>
<input type="text" id="calculation_input" />
<p id="display_result"></p>
```

You don't need to submit the calculation in a form, you can just use native javascript to calculate the result. And don't forget to always sanitize before using `eval` :)

Answer (score 0):

see the below fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/ponmudi/13y9edve/

```
num_field = document.getElementById("calc");
num_field.onkeydown = (event) => {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        document.getElementById("display_result").innerHTML = eval(num_field.value);
        return false;
    }
}
```