# Sum up html string numbers using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I have a function that returns numbers inside a `<p>` tag with the following format:

```
<p class="numbers">123 + 456 + 789</p>
```

Is there any way I can do another function or something in javascript to sum up all the numbers and store it into a variable?

Thanks!

Comment: [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) could help

Comment: eval seems to do the job. thank you!

Comment: eval is evil. be careful while using it @cup_of

Comment: ok thanks for letting me know that @AnikIslamAbhi

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate string value in javascript, not using eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479236/calculate-string-value-in-javascript-not-using-eval)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// Grab the element
const para = document.querySelector('.numbers');

// Convert the text content to an array and
// make the text number values into actual numbers
const numbers = para.textContent.split(' + ').map(Number);

// Use `reduce` to sum the numbers
const total = numbers.reduce((p, c) => p + c);
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/2k71ff55/1/)

Comment: What occurs if middle portion of string is `- 456`?

Comment: That's not the question.

Comment: @Andy Fair enough

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
var string = "<p class="numbers">123 + 456 + 789</p>";
var numbers = string.split(">")[1].split("<")[0].split("+");
var i = 0;
var sum = 0;
while(i < numbers.length){
    sum += parseInt(numbers[i]);
    i += 1;
}
return sum;
```

Comment: One thing to be careful of -- this assumes the numbers are integers. Maybe that's a safe assumption or maybe not, but it will give the wrong answer if you have values like 123.5.

Comment: Yeah, that's true, but if not you can just swap in "parseFloat", so it shouldn't be a huge problem

Comment: If you're going to use `parseInt` you should include the radix for completeness: `parseInt(numbers[i], 10)`.

Comment: If you don't need to support older browsers (like IE 11) Number() is a nice alternative to parseInt/parseFloat.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce()`

```js
var n = document.querySelector(".numbers").textContent;

var nums = n.replace(/\s/g, "").match(/^\d+|[+-]\d+/g);

var res = nums.reduce((a, b) => Number(a) + Number(b));

document.body.innerHTML += `=${res}`;
```

```html
<p class="numbers">123 + 456 + 789</p>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer I gave you an upvote but Ive already selected andys answer. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

var x = document.querySelector('.numbers').textContent.split("+").map(Number);

var y = x.reduce(function(add,num){return add+num})

console.log(y);