# How to transform string into integers and operators in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, calculator

I am making a four function calculator with javascript. I am storing the button presses in an array 'tmp', removing operators from the beginning and end of the array, converting to a string, and removing commas.

Any given string should be properly formatted for calculation except for the fact that it's in a string. What's the best way to get it out of the string and calculated?

thanks!

Comment: So if your input is `"-4*2"` you're doing `4*2` ? Is that a good idea? Also if you have say this input: `"-1+2*2/"` and you get this array: `["1", "+", "2", "*", "2"]` what's your expected result?

Comment: regex's with capture groups.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan [-,4,*,2] turns out to be "-4*2". /[+*/]/g is my regex for that. ["1", "+", "2", "*", "2"] should return 5, as per pemdas. Although, I could iterate from left to right if I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
// Array of inputs in you calculator
const inputs = ["1", "+", "2", "*", "2"];

// inputs.join(" ") turns the array into "1 + 2 * 2" string
// and the fn() returns the result
const fn = new Function("return " + inputs.join(" "));

console.log(fn()); // 5
```

Comment: With considerations to [this answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479236/calculate-string-value-in-javascript-not-using-eval)

Comment: Not sure I should give any credits when I thought of this on my own ...

Comment: I'm sure you did. Rephrased my comment.

Comment: That got me where I needed to go. Thank you much!