# How to convert a string into a mathematical expression?

Tags: javascript, string

I am trying to convert a string into mathematical expression, so I can calculate the value, but when I use the `parseInt` method it returns NAN:

```
function cal() {
  const data = '(2 * 3 + 2) * (2 / 2)';
  const info = data.replace(/\s/g, '');
  const output = parseInt(info, 10);
  console.log(output);
}
cal();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate string value in javascript, not using eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479236/calculate-string-value-in-javascript-not-using-eval)

Answer (score 4):

See Javascript [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

```js
function cal() {
  const data = eval('(2 * 3 + 2) * (2 / 2)');
  const output = parseInt(data, 10);
  console.log(output);
}
cal();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use eval
**Example :**

```js
const data = '(2 * 3 + 2) * (2 / 2)';

const result = eval(data)

console.log(result)
```