# Math Equation Algorithm Javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm

for example, if I had a STRING = "3+3*(4-1)"
if a ran a function and wanted it to solve the equation using javascript, what Would I start with?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276021/evaluating-a-string-as-a-mathematical-expression-in-javascript

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479236/calculate-string-value-in-javascript-not-using-eval

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the equation has a correct syntax of javascript, you can use `eval` to evaluate the value.

i.e.
`eval("3+3*(4-1)")` = 12