# Single-Variable Symbolic Differentiation from Expression Trees

Tags: javascript, symbolic-math, derivative

I'm trying to find the best method/algorithm for computing the derivative of a typed mathematical function in Javascript symbolically. Each equation will only have a single variable.
I started with a typed expression which is then converted to [RPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) (reverse polish notation) using Dijkstra's [shunting-yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) to convert the infix equation into a postfix one. My next ideas was to use this to create an expression tree, which ends up looking something like this:

```
Equation: 25x^2 + 61x + 3

RPN: 25 x 2 ^ * 61 x * + 3 +
```

Expression tree:
[image: Expression tree]

I looked at what the "solved" expression tree should look like to get an idea of what needed to be done:
[image: Solved tree]

```
Derivative (without simplification): x^(2-1)*2*25+61
```

I was thinking I could recursively apply the differentiation rules (product, quotient, sum, difference, etc) using a [postorder traversal](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tree-traversals-inorder-preorder-and-postorder/) and replace the "nodes" depending on the operator.

However, after looking at the derivative's expression tree, I realized that I couldn't easily apply something like the product rule to a node that still had children (ie. [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRJMl.png))

So my primary question is: Are there any known algorithms similar to shunting-yard for efficiently computing symbolic derivatives programmatically?

Comment: Your question might be better suited for https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

The Shunting Yard algorithm is more about parsing than transformation, so it seems IMHO that it is better to traverse the resulting expression tree, building the derivative expression in a separate tree.  For simple expressions the replace-in-place might appear to be the solution, but as the mathematical expressions become more complex, the differentiation rules (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_rules) will make the tree operations complex, especially as the algorithm dives into the child nodes to further differentiate.  For example...

- The product rule is f(x) g(x) = f'(x) g(x) + f(x) g'(x)

...and thus, to differentiate the following...

- x * ln( x )

...results in...

- ( x )' * ln( x ) + x * ( ln( x ) )'
- 1    * ln( x ) + x *     1/x

I think you will also find that once the derivative is created, that there will need to be some algebraic cleanup of the expression.  Following the example, the algorithm will need a second pass to walk the derivative tree and simplify the expression based on algebraic rules, for example...

- 1 * n  =  n
- n * 1 / n  =  1

...so the final result is...

- ln( x ) + 1

There's actually a great resource at https://www.derivative-calculator.net/ that is an implementation of what you are seeking to do in code, and might be worthwhile experimenting with to get a feel for the logic involved.  Additionally, there is an excellent implementation of the Shunting Yard algorithm at [Calculate string value in javascript, not using eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479236/calculate-string-value-in-javascript-not-using-eval/47761792#47761792).