# How to replace JavaScript template

Tags: javascript

I have an input like this:

```
var input = "text {{ variable*100 }} text {{ variable }} text {{ variable+2 }}";
```

and I have a variable :

```
var varible = 2;
```

I want to replace the text inside the `{{}}` with the value of the variable and calculate if needed

I'm expecting the result to be :

```
"text 200 text 2 text 102"
```

I've tried this code :

```js
var tooltip = 'text {{ damage*100 }} text {{ damage }} text {{mana-1}}';

var objMap = {
    damage: 100,
    defence: 26,
    mana: 100,
}

var replaced = tooltip.replace(/(\{{.*?\}})/g, function (m, $1) {
    var key = $1.slice(2, -2).trim();
    return objMap[key];
});

console.log(replaced)
```

and I got this result :

```
text undefined text 100 text undefined
```

Comment: What about using template strings instead? `\`text ${damage*100} text\``

Comment: consider also using something like mustache

Comment: its an input i fetch it form an api i cant hard code it

Comment: This could be dynamic too? [Using tagged template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#tagged_templates)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's *possible* to dynamically parse out the variable names from the other math done inside the brackets and then `eval` the result (making sure it only contains the sorts of characters permitted in a plain math expression first, so that it's safe):

```js
var tooltip = 'text {{ damage*100 }} text {{ damage }} text {{mana-1}}';

var objMap = {
    damage: 100,
    defence: 26,
    mana: 100,
}

var replaced = tooltip.replace(/\{{(.*?)\}}/g, (_, innerText) => {
    const innerTextReplaced = innerText.replace(/[a-z]+/gi, word => objMap[word]);
    // make sure the text is now only a plain math expression
    // with no characters other than numbers and operators
    if (!innerTextReplaced.match(/^[ \d()\/*+-]+$/)) {
      throw new Error('Potentially unsafe input detected');
    }
    return eval(innerTextReplaced);
});

console.log(replaced)
```

If you don't want to use `eval`, I suppose you can use `new Function`, but it's unlikely to matter:

```js
var tooltip = 'text {{ damage*100 }} text {{ damage }} text {{mana-1}}';

var objMap = {
    damage: 100,
    defence: 26,
    mana: 100,
}

var replaced = tooltip.replace(/\{{(.*?)\}}/g, (_, innerText) => {
    const innerTextReplaced = innerText.replace(/[a-z]+/gi, word => objMap[word]);
    // make sure the text is now only a plain math expression
    // with no characters other than numbers and operators
    if (!innerTextReplaced.match(/^[ \d()\/*+-]+$/)) {
      throw new Error('Potentially unsafe input detected');
    }
    return Function('return ' + innerTextReplaced)();
});

console.log(replaced)
```

But if at all possible, I'd much prefer a function instead of a string for the input:

```js
var objMap = {
    damage: 100,
    defence: 26,
    mana: 100,
}

const makeTooltip = ({ damage, defence, mana }) => `text ${ damage*100 } text ${ damage } text ${mana-1}`;
console.log(makeTooltip(objMap));
```

Comment: Worth noting that this is incredibly insecure

Comment: thanks using `eval` solve my problem 
i cant use es6 literals bc the text is from an API request

Comment: Please read [Never use eval()!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#never_use_eval!)

Comment: @ThomasSablik If the input can be sanitized - which isn't hard - I don't think there's anything wrong with it. https://stackoverflow.com/q/6479236 unless this runs in a really tight loop

Comment: Do you really expect a beginner to sanitize the input. You didn't even mention it in your answer. You gave a child a gun to play with.

Comment: @ThomasSablik I said `(making sure it only contains the sorts of characters permitted in a plain math expression first, so that it's safe)` and also in a comment `// make sure the text is now only a plain math expression` `// with no characters other than numbers and operators` and a demonstration with `if (!innerTextReplaced.match(/^[ \d()\/*+-]+$/)) {`.

Comment: @ThomasSablik the input is a fetch from an API the API is safe im using the Function constructor now because I read in [Never use eval()!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#never_use_eval!) that `eval()` is unsafe

Comment: @AmineBeihaqi Both `eval` and `new Function` have the same security vulnerabilities, both of which can be remedied by making sure the input is trustworthy first, which the `innerTextReplaced.match(/^[ \d()\/*+-]+$/)` properly detects and fixes.

Comment: @AminaBeihaqi Network data and user input are never trustworthy. And that you didn't know it proves my statement.