# How can I make multilevel object from string, which has structure like logic expression?

Tags: javascript, typescript, algorithm

As beginner, I don't know what is I can start from. I need to implement function which will transform string to object with particular structure like I wrote below (original string may be with other number of levels, conditionals etc.):

```js
const str = `time !== 10 && (state === 'Ready' || state === 'Pending')`;

const result = {
  and: [
    {
      field: 'time',
      expression: '!==',
      value: 10
    },
    {
      or: [
        {
          field: 'state',
          expression: '===',
          value: 'Ready'
        },
        {
          field: 'state',
          expression: '===',
          value: 'Pending'
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You want to create Abstract Syntax Tree (AST). Take a look on `github/esprima` for exmaple

Comment: What you are looking for is a parser library.

Comment: You say you're a beginner.. Sorry to say but seems like this is not a problem for a beginner to solve. Maybe start with something a little easier?  :D

Comment: A great implementation of the Shunting Yard algorithm can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479236/calculate-string-value-in-javascript-not-using-eval/47761792#47761792

Answer (score 1):

The structure you mention is called an [Abstract Syntax Tree (AST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree). This is a commom data structure that can represent the abstract structure of a word belonging to a language.

Your strings seem to be written in the infix order: you can try to implement the [shunting yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) to build the AST from the string.

As said in a comment, this is not a beginner problem. It would be better if you had some prior experience in data structures, algorithms, theory of languages/automata, and computer programming before implementing the shunting yard algorithm.